# Exception in Thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"

Tags: java

I am trying to load data from spreadsheet to a database, but received below exception error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at postressqlconnection.dbconnection.main(dbconnection.java:124)

I am new to java and any help will be appreceiated.

Java code

```
public class dbconnection {

/**
 * 
 */
static DataInputStream dis;
static Connection databaseConnection;
static FileInputStream fis;
static BufferedInputStream bis;
static File file;



private static void openFile(String taxitraces) {

    File file = new File(taxitraces);
    try 
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(dbconnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,       null, ex);
    }

}

public static void connectDB(String host,String port,String dbname,String username,String passwd) 
{
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.print("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? Include    in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try 
        {
            databaseConnection =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbname, username, passwd);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (databaseConnection == null)
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        else
            System.out.println("Connected to: "+"jdbc:postgresql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+dbname);
}

public static void closeFile() {
    try 
    {
        if(fis != null) fis.close();
        if(bis != null) bis.close();
        if(dis != null) dis.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(dbconnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    file = null;
    fis = null;
    bis = null;
    dis = null;
}

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws NumberFormatException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String fileName = "****";
    String host="***";
    String port="***";
    String dbname="***";
    String username="***";
    String passwd="***";

    openFile(fileName);

    connectDB(host,port,dbname,username,passwd);
    Statement sql=null;
    try {
         sql = databaseConnection.createStatement();
    }catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Could not create statement in JDBC: " + e.getErrorCode());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(dis.available() != 0){
        try {
            // read line
            String[] fileData;
            String line = dis.readLine().replaceAll("\"", "");
            fileData = line.split(",");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[0]);
            int driver_id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[1]);
            String timestamp = fileData[2];
            boolean in_service = Boolean.parseBoolean(fileData[3]);
            int trips_pos = Integer.parseInt(fileData[4]);
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(fileData[5]);
            double lon = Double.parseDouble(fileData[6]);
            int parish_id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[7]);
            double distance = Double.parseDouble(fileData[8]);
            int duration = Integer.parseInt(fileData[9]);
            int trip_id = Integer.parseInt(fileData[10]);
            double taxi_fare = Double.parseDouble(fileData[11]);



            String query = " INSERT INTO aid_atidivyakumarpatra "
                    + "(id, driver_id, timestamp, in_service, trip_pos,lat, lon, parish_id, distamce, duration, trip_id, taxi_fare)"
                    + "VALUES ("+id+",'"+driver_id+"',"+timestamp+","+in_service+","+trips_pos+","
                    + lat+","+lon+",ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+lat+" "+lon+")', 4326) , "+parish_id+","+distance+", "
                    + duration+","+trip_id +","+taxi_fare +")";

            try {
                System.out.println(query);
                sql.executeUpdate(query);

            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Could not create statement in JDBC: " + e.getErrorCode());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //…
        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(dbconnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    closeFile();

}
```

}

Comment: Exception stack has all information required for you to fix the problem. 1) dbconnection.java:124 2) .NumberFormatException: For input string: "id" at

Comment: You are trying to parse a string with value "`id`" to an integer. How do you expect that to work. As to why: you need to look at your input file. Clearly a column (first or second?) does not have integer values, or maybe you have to skip the first line (eg because it contains column headers)

Comment: Can you give us a sample line of the file data, or copy in the output given when you add a `System.out.println(line);` in your while loop before you `.split()` it?  The issue seems to be a wayward string in the input data rather than a coding problem.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel: Thank you, I removed the column headers and now it worked for me.